# How to send request payload as parameter in python web scraping?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I am doing web scraping in python using requests of the following [website](https://easyauto123.com.au/buy/used-cars/filter/fuel-type).

Here in inspect element when you will load the data of any fuel type, you will see a API being triggered by name `getFilteredInventery`.

Suppose, you have selected Diesel, then I want to scrape all the data which is visible in response section of given API. But I cannot simply open it. In headers section you will see request payload and I think I have send it too as parameter.

I surfed internet and I found out that I can send request payload as param in requests.

This is my code:

```
payload = {"Search": {"FuelType": ["Diesel"]}, "Sort": {"Featured": "true"}}
url = "https://easyauto123.com.au/api/v1/getFilteredInventory"
page = requests.get(url, params=payload)
data = page.json()
```

But the page is showing 400 error. So, how could I get this error solved?

API Link: https://easyauto123.com.au/api/v1/getFilteredInventory

Comment: You use GET method, maybe try using POST method?
page = requests.post(url, data=payload)

Add a link to the API, please)

Comment: API Link has been added and thanks a lot, it worked by using POST instead of GET. If you have time, maybe you can enter this comment as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You variant:

```
page = requests.get(url, params=payload)
```

Try this variant:

```
page = requests.post(url, json=payload)
```

Comment: Oops! I wasn't paying attention and didn't notice that you'd already answered this question. I included quite a bit of technical detail [in mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69752117/118912). Please feel free to borrow any of it that you'd like (or not.)

Answer (score 4):

The code example you posted results in the `requests` library making a `GET` request to the URL with the "payload" you've defined turned into query parameters and returns a 404. You can see this for yourself like this:

```
payload = {"Search": {"FuelType": ["Diesel"]}, "Sort": {"Featured": "true"}}
url = "https://easyauto123.com.au/api/v1/getFilteredInventory"
page = requests.get(url, params=payload)

print(page.url)
# => https://easyauto123.com.au/api/v1/getFilteredInventory?Search=FuelType&Sort=Featured
print(page.status_code)
```

The API is expecting a `POST` request with a JSON payload, which is typically signified during the request by the HTTP header `Content-Type` having a value of `application/json`.) The `requests` library exposes this functionality:

```
page = requests.post(url, json=payload)
```

You can evaluate the request headers used for a particular request via the stored `request` attribute of the returned object:

```
page = requests.post(url, json=payload)

print(page.request.headers)
# => {'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.25.1', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Content-Length': '66', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'

print(page.request.headers['Content-Type'])
# => application/json
```

You can compare this with the request that results from the following:

```
page = requests.post(url, params=payload)
print(page.request.url)
# => https://easyauto123.com.au/api/v1/getFilteredInventory?Search=FuelType&Sort=Featured

print(page.request.headers)
# => {'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.25.1', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Content-Length': '0'}
```

You may notice that this request succeeds, though the response body is different. Also, note the `Content-Length` header's value is `0` (vs `66`) and that the `Content-Type` header is not set. The `Content-Length` header denotes the size of the payload, which in this case is `0`.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer.